# R programming: Creating a list of paired elements

Tags: r, regex, list, substr

I have a list of elements say:

```
l <- c("x","ya1","xb3","yb3","ab","xc3","y","xa1","yd4")
```

Out of this list I would like to make a list of the matching x,y pairs, i.e.

```
(("xa1" "ya1") ("xb3" "yb3") ("x" "y"))
```

In essence, I need to capture the X elements, the Y elements and then pair them up:
I know how to do the X,Y extraction part:

```
xelems <- grep("^x", l, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
yelems <- grep("^y", l, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

An X element pairs up with a Y element when

```
1. xElem == yElem # if xElem and yElem are one char long, i.e. 'x' and 'y'    
2. substr(xElem,1,nchar(xElem)) == substr(yElem,1,nchar(yElem))
```

There is no order, i.e. matching xElem and yElem can be positioned anywhere.

I am however not very sure about the next part. I am more familiar with the [SKILL programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence_SKILL) (SKILL is a LISP derivative) and this is how I write it:

```
procedure( get_xy_pairs(inputList "l")
  let(( yElem (xyPairs nil) xList yList)
    xList=setof(i inputList rexMatchp("^x" i))
    yList=setof(i inputList rexMatchp("^y" i))
    when(xList && yList
      unless(length(xList)==length(yList)
    warn("xList and yList mismatch : %d vs %d\n" length(xList) length(yList))
      )
      foreach(xElem xList
        if(xElem=="x"
          then yElem="y"
          else yElem=strcat("y" substring(xElem 2 strlen(xElem)))
        )
        if(member(yElem yList)
          then xyPairs=cons(list(xElem yElem) xyPairs)
          else warn("x element %s has no matching y element \n" xElem)
        )
      )
    )
    xyPairs
  )
)
```

When run on l, this would return

```
get_xy_pairs(l)
*WARNING* x element xc3 has no matching y element 
(("xa1" "ya1") ("xb3" "yb3") ("x" "y"))
```

As I am still new to **R**, I would appreciate if you folks can help. Besides, I do understand the **R** folks tend to avoid for loops and are more into lapply ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work. (Only tested on your sample data.)

```
## Remove any item not starting with x or y
l2 <- l[grepl("^x|^y", l)]

## Split into a list of items starting with x
##   and items starting with y
L <- split(l2, grepl("^x", l2))

## Give "names" to the "starting with y" group
names(L[[1]]) <- gsub("^y", "x", L[[1]])

## Use match to match the names in the y group with
##   the values from the x group. This results in a
##   nice named vector with the pairs you want
Matches <- L[[1]][match(L[[2]], names(L[[1]]), nomatch=0)]
Matches
#     x   xb3   xa1 
#   "y" "yb3" "ya1"
```

As a `data.frame`:

```
MatchesDF <- data.frame(x = names(Matches), y = unname(Matches))
MatchesDF
#     x   y
# 1   x   y
# 2 xb3 yb3
# 3 xa1 ya1
```

Comment: Ananda, thank you so much for your solution, works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

I would store tuples in a list, i.e:

```
xypairs
[[1]]
[1] "x"    "y"

[[2]]
[2] "xb3"  "yb3"
```

Your procedure can be simplified with `match` and `substring`.

```
xends <- substring(xelems, 2)
yends <- substring(yelems, 2)
ypaired <- match(xends, yends)  # Indices of yelems that match xelems

# Now we need to handle the no-matches:
xsorted <- c(xelems, rep(NA, sum(is.na(ypaired))))
ysorted <- yelems[ypaired]
ysorted <- c(ysorted, yelems[!(yelems %in% ysorted)])

# Now we create the list of tuples:
xypairs <- lapply(1:length(ysorted), function(i) {
  c(xsorted[i], ysorted[i])
})
```

Result:

```
xypairs
[[1]]
[1] "x" "y"

[[2]]
[1] "xb3" "yb3"

[[3]]
[1] "xc3" NA   

[[4]]
[1] "xa1" "ya1"

[[5]]
[1] NA    "yd4"
```

Comment: Manetheran, Thx a lot for your contribution, very much appreciated !